# SQLAlchemy, how to filter by empty array column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have that kind of Model in SQLAlchemy:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_models'
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    company_ids = Column(ARRAY(Integer), nullable=True)
```

I have intentionally created models with empty arrays and try to query them like this:

```
db.query(MyModel).filter(~MyModel.company_ids.any())
```

Which doesn't return anything.

**Is it possible to filter models that have empty array field?**

**============UPDATE===============**

I was able to query it by using this method:

```
db.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.company_ids == '{}')
```

However I think it is only PostgreSQL specific answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to query it by using this method:

```
db.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.company_ids == '{}')
```

However I think it is only PostgreSQL specific answer

Answer (score 0):

I think SQLAlchemy's way of doing this is

```
db.query(MyModel).filter(
 func.cardinality(MyModel.company_ids == 0)
)
```